# Lua.h functions definitions not found

Tags: visual-studio-2015, lua

I'm implementing Lua in my c++ project but I'm getting unresolved external symbols errors because the Lua.h is not finding the functions definition. 
I have added the path to the lua.lib in "Additional library directories", the lua.lib in "Aditional dependencies" and the include folder with the headers (lua.h, lua.hpp, luaconf.h,lualib.h, luaxlib.h) in the include directories.

[image]

I'm using visual studio community 2015 and lua is 5.3.3 from [Lua Binaries](https://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/5.3.3/Windows%20Libraries/Dynamic/) "lua-5.3.3_Win32_dll14_lib.zip" this one is the win32 version dynamic but I tested with win32 static and win64 dynamic and static and it's the same result.

Any idea?

Comment: The library binary is one of the two things you need. You also need the library headers. Add the path that `lua.h`, etc. are in to your includes path.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo i have already done that i forgot to put it on the post.

Answer (score 1):

When using Lua from a C++ application, you need to **`#include "lua.hpp"`** rather than `lua.h`.

If you glance at the contents of `lua.hpp` you'll see why :) It just wraps the Lua headers in `extern "C"`, as is needed for a C++ compiler to recognized those Lua function definitions as using the C ABI (without which the linker will be looking for the wrong symbols in the DLL).

Comment: that's what i did and as you see I'm getting this error

Comment: The reason for a separate lua.hpp file is that Lua can be compiled as a C++ library, with C++ error handling. See http://lua-users.org/wiki/BuildingLua.

Comment: @lhf Ah thanks for the link, I understand the rationale now.  Removed my ignorant comment :)

Comment: @TinoTano Sorry, when I saw lua.h in your editor above I assumed you were including it rather than lua.hpp.  In that case, would you consider adding the full build error log to your original post?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that now it's working.

All I did is change the dynamic lib to static lib and rebuild solution and now it's working but if I enter in Lua.h I see the same problem with functions declarations but now it works without errors...